# Horizontal Scroll Bar in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid at two places in my Project .

In first sample code it is running perfect with horizontal bar showing up ...

Sample Code for first jqGrid
Sample Code :

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'server1.php?P1=ACNO,APHID',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:[
        'ACNO','APHID'
    ],
    colModel:[
        {name:'ACNO',index:'ACNO', width:80, sortable:true, search:true},
        {name:'APHID',index:'APHID', width:80, sortable:true, search:true}
    ],
    rowNum:100,
    rowList:[100,200,300,400],
    pager: '#pager2',
    loadonce: true,
    sortname: 'geneID',
    viewrecords: true,
    width:700,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    height:700,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Breeder Tool Box"
});
```

Sample Code for  the second jqGrid
Sample Code :

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'server4.php?P1=NEMATODE',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Linkage_group','Chromosome','Start_Position','Stop_Position','Start','End','geneID','Feature_Type','Feature_Name','Mstart','Mstop','Trait'],
    colModel:[
        {index: 'Linkage_group', name: 'Linkage_group',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'Chromosome', name: 'Chromosome',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'Start_Position', name: 'StartPos',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'Stop_Position', name: 'StopPos',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'Start', name: 'Start',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'End', name: 'End',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'geneID', name: 'geneID',width:170, sortable:true, search:true,formatter: formatOperations},
        {index: 'Feature_Type', name: 'Feature_Type',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'Feature_Name', name: 'Feature_Name',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'Mstart', name: 'Mstart',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'Mstop', name: 'Mstop',width:170, sortable:true, search:true},
        {index: 'Trait', name: 'Trait',width:170, sortable:true, search:true}],
    rowNum:100,
    rowList:[100,200,300,400],
    pager: '#pager2',
    loadonce: true,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    viewrecords: true,
    width:700,
    height:700,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Breeder Tool Box",
    sortname: 'Linkage_group'
});
```

jqGrid for the second grid is all distorted with no horizontal bar .
I am not able to find the differences between these two codes ,
 Can you please point where is my mistake ?

Comment: I suppose that the problem with horizontal bar not in the code which you posted. It should be in the code over the posted code. It can be some problems with HTML or CSS for example.

Comment: I am not sure, that you understand correct the meaning of `index` property. In the second grid you use different values for `index` and `name` (`index: 'Start_Position', name: 'StartPos'` and `index: 'Stop_Position', name: 'StopPos'`). In the first grid you defines `sortname: 'geneID'` and has no column `'geneID'`. All the problems are independent from the horizontal bar issue, but there are errors. Properties `search` and `sortable` has default values `true`, so you can remove there. If you want change default properties for columns you can use `cmTemplate: {width:170}` and reduce your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this with css. Change the following in `ui.grid.css`

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
  position: relative; 
  margin: 0em; 
  padding:0; 
  /*overflow: auto;*/ 
  overflow-x:visible; 
  overflow-y:auto; 
  text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: I  changed in CSS but I don't see a difference. It is all distorted again .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It helped me to resolve the issue :).