# jqgrid v4.4.5 rtl horizontal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jqgrid

[image]I use jqgrid v4.4.5 and jquery v1.9.1.
When I resize jqgrid and the horizontal scrollbar appears  it work on IE and Firefox. but  in Chrome not work ,columns truncated and wrong width calculation.

How can i solve this?

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
            direction:"rtl",
            url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['UserID', 'UserName', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName', 'EmailID'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'UserID', index: 'UserID', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'UserName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'FirstName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'MiddleName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'LastName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'EmailID', width: 150, sortable: true }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#UsersGridPager',
            sortname: 'UserID',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            caption: 'JSON Example'
        });

        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As given in the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) the `shrinkToFit` property if set, defines how the the width of the columns of the grid should be re-calculated, taking into consideration the width of the grid. If this value is true, and the width of the columns is also set, then every column is scaled in proportion to its width.

> When set to true, the grid width is recalculated automatically to the width of the parent element. This is done only initially when the grid is created. In order to resize the grid when the parent element changes width you should apply custom code and use a setGridWidth method for this purpose.

So you can just add the property to the jqGrid as :

```
shrinkToFit:true,
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.i set shrinkToFit:true but it still does not work.

Comment: @Ajo Koshy , its quite long with server side functionality, which specific part of it do you need ?

Comment: @buzibuzi the grid part

Comment: here: http://jsfiddle.net/buzibuzi/rVNLu/
btw, i used this thread to solve this probelm:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253939/horizontal-scroll-bar-in-jqgrid/8254665#8254665